# Parameterized queries WITHOUT stored procedures?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, parameterized

Every sample I've seen uses stored procedures.  I've adopted an old application written in Classic ASP that uses inline SQL.  This is an obvious issue, so I need to convert it to safer code.  The client does not wish that I use stored procedures in this application, so is there a way to run parameterized queries without stored procedures?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Have a look at some of these examples:

http://www.securestate.blogspot.com/2008/09/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention_30.html
http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=119&p7=3001

Comment: Just tested.  Doesn't seem to load without the www but its fine with it.  Thanks!

Comment: The approach in the second link is my preference, the problem with the approach in the first link is it round trips to the SQL server whilst preparing the parameter set, the second approach doesn't do that since it creates the parameters explicitly.

Comment: The '%5F' in the URL causes a 404. Some browsers probably convert that to '_', which is why it works for some and not others.

Comment: The second link seems dead, but this works: http://web.archive.org/web/20130205075003/http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=119&p7=3001

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why the client doesn't want to use stored procedures?  It is much easier to use stored procedures both on the database level as well as in your source code.  You should get query plan caching on your inline query if you use the second method from above, but depending on what you are doing you might be better off with simple sprocs if you can convince your client that it's ok to use them.  If all else fails the links above are pretty solid, especially the second one.

Comment: -1: "easier" is subjective, and the use of stored procedures is not a guarantee against SQL injection.

Comment: I don't think for a minute that this is a subjective thing. This is a standard concept of multi-tier development, separating your logic and data tiers. I also never said that stored procedures _guarantee_ protection against SQL injection. Parameterized queries and stored procedures will prevent many situations that happen from lazy coding allowing SQL injection, but it doesnt prevent dynamic queries in sprocs from being vulnerable among other things.  A down vote seems pretty inappropriate considering this was a valid and insightful response.